# Create virtualenv in Python 2.7 on windows 10 while other virtualenv are working in Python 3.8

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv

I'm unable to install a virtual environment in Python 2.7. Whenever I try this command
`py -m pip install --user virtualenv`
or
`py -m pip install --user venv`
it shows requirements are already satisfied in 3.8. Although I've activated the Python 2.7 and in cmd py simply typing `python` it shows the
`Python 2.7.12rc1 (v2.7.12rc1:13912cd1e7e8, Jun 12 2016, 05:51:33) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32`

**Please guide me on how can I install a virtual environment in Python 2.7 and I don't want to uninstall/remove Python3.8 Please lemme know if you need further explanation. Thanks a lot***

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you have multiple version of Python installed on a Windows PC, you can use the specific **Python.exe** files to control which version you're working with

```
PS C:\> .\Python27\python.exe --version
Python 2.7.9
PS C:\> .\Python37\python.exe --version
Python 3.7.7
```

The same rule applies for **pip**

```
PS C:\> .\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe --version
pip 20.2.4 from C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip (python 2.7)
PS C:\> .\Python37\Scripts\pip.exe --version
pip 20.2.4 from c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)
```

You need to ensure that you've installed **virtualenv** using the Python 2.7 version of pip, and verify it's using the correct python version by checking the path

```
PS C:\> .\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe install virtualenv
PS C:\> .\Python27\Scripts\virtualenv.exe --version
virtualenv 20.1.0 from c:\python27\lib\site-packages\virtualenv\__init__.pyc
```

I have a Python 3.7 version installed as well for this demonstration

```
PS C:\> .\Python37\Scripts\virtualenv.exe --version
virtualenv 20.1.0 from c:\python37\lib\site-packages\virtualenv\__init__.py
```

Then create your virtual environment using the version that you want, activate it and it should be the version of Python you want

```
PS C:\> .\Python27\Scripts\virtualenv.exe py2env
PS C:\> .\py2env\Scripts\activate
(py2env) PS C:\> python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:28:03) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

And finally, the Python 3.7 example

```
PS C:\> .\Python37\Scripts\virtualenv.exe py3env
PS C:\> .\py3env\Scripts\activate
(py3env) PS C:\> python
Python 3.7.7 (tags/v3.7.7:d7c567b08f, Mar 10 2020, 10:41:24) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Comment: Yes you declared the right way but now I'm having another issue. I used the following commands in order

`C:\>python27\Scripts\pip.exe --version
pip 8.1.1 from c:\python27\lib\site-packages (python 2.7)

C:\>python27\Scripts\pip.exe install virtualenv
Collecting virtualenv`

and it prints nothing else. I mean it's not installing virtualenv. As when I check for virtualenv version, it says

`C:\>python27\Scripts\virtualenv.exe --version
'python27\Scripts\virtualenv.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Please elaborate it.

Comment: @MuhammadAfzaal - oh, definitely upgrade pip! Then try again; you're using a super older version...`C:\>python27\Scripts\pip.exe install pip --upgrade`

Comment: I got this message
`DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.`

Comment: @MuhammadAfzaal - Yes Python 2 is deprecated; please move all projects to Python 3 ASAP. But your pip should still have been updated to **20.2.4**; same version as mine as I literally did this today to write this post

Comment: Actually as mentioned in the title, I'm already using python3.8 and its virtual environments are working fine. But for a specific project, I need Python 2.7 environment. 
So what's your suggestion on this scenario.

Comment: @MuhammadAfzaal - Before we change topics; has your question been answered? If so, kindly mark the answer as accepted. In regards to your Python 2 project; my recommendation is to rebuild or refactor to Python 3. Python 2 is no longer maintained, and once **pip** moves to version 21 you won't be able to install any new packages

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224889/discussion-between-muhammad-afzaal-and-louiec).